# Django Wsgi ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project_name'

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, uwsgi

I am trying to deploy a Django project using WSGI and NGINX. The problem is that at startup, the logs show a module missing error

When launched via the `service uwsgi restart` command, an error appears in the logs /var/log/uwsgi/app/django.log:

```
Wed Aug 18 17:25:21 2021 - Python version: 3.8.10 (default, Jun  2 2021, 10:49:15)  [GCC 9.4.0]
Wed Aug 18 17:25:21 2021 - *** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Wed Aug 18 17:25:21 2021 - Python main interpreter initialized at 0x55f90e1e7700
Wed Aug 18 17:25:21 2021 - your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
Wed Aug 18 17:25:21 2021 - your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
Wed Aug 18 17:25:21 2021 - mapped 145840 bytes (142 KB) for 1 cores
Wed Aug 18 17:25:21 2021 - *** Operational MODE: single process ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "project_name/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project_name'
Wed Aug 18 17:25:22 2021 - unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
Wed Aug 18 17:25:22 2021 - *** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
Wed Aug 18 17:25:22 2021 - *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
Wed Aug 18 17:25:22 2021 - spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 223091)
Wed Aug 18 17:25:22 2021 - spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 223102, cores: 1)
```

wsgi.py:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project_name.settings.production')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

/etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/django.ini:

```
 [uwsgi]
    chdir = /root/project_name
    env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project_name.settings.production
    wsgi-file = project_name/wsgi.py
    workers = 1
    plugins = python3
```

wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project_name.settings.production')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

.
structure /root/project_name/..

```
    ├── project_name
    │   ├── asgi.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── settings
    │   │   ├── base.py
    │   │   ├── development.py
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   ├── production.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   └── wsgi.py
    ├── manage.py
    ├── web_site
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── apps.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   └── views.py
```

Because of what could this be? How to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Your project folders may need adding to path in wsgi.py, as per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42981216/10905324

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/django_projects/MyProject')
sys.path.append('/home/django_projects/MyProject/project_name')

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project_name.settings.production')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```