# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'commerce.wsgi' Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my django application to Heroku using github (downloaded zip file) but receiving this error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'commerce.wsgi'. I've made some edits with previous stackoverflow responses to questions like this but having same error.
[Django Wsgi ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project_name'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68834468/django-wsgi-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-project-name)

HEROKU PAGE

```
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail
```

WSGI.PY

```
"""
WSGI config for commerce project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/home/django_projects/commerce')
sys.path.append('/home/django_projects/commerce/commerce')

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'commerce.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

PROCFILE

```
web: gunicorn commerce.wsgi
```

HEROKU LOG TAIL

```
 
2022-03-20T22:12:10.677933+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2022-03-20T22:12:10.677933+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2022-03-20T22:12:10.677933+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2022-03-20T22:12:10.677933+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2022-03-20T22:12:10.677934+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2022-03-20T22:12:10.677934+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2022-03-20T22:12:10.677935+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2022-03-20T22:12:10.677935+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2022-03-20T22:12:10.677935+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2022-03-20T22:12:10.677935+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2022-03-20T22:12:10.677936+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2022-03-20T22:12:10.677936+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'commerce.wsgi'
2022-03-20T22:12:10.678109+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-20 22:12:10 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2022-03-20T22:12:10.682933+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-20 22:12:10 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2022-03-20T22:12:10.711262+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-20 22:12:10 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2022-03-20T22:12:10.711264+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-03-20T22:12:10.711267+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2022-03-20T22:12:10.711267+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2022-03-20T22:12:10.711268+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2022-03-20T22:12:10.711268+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2022-03-20T22:12:10.711268+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2022-03-20T22:12:10.711269+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2022-03-20T22:12:10.711269+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2022-03-20T22:12:10.711269+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2022-03-20T22:12:10.711270+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2022-03-20T22:12:10.711270+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2022-03-20T22:12:10.711270+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2022-03-20T22:12:10.711271+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2022-03-20T22:12:10.711271+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2022-03-20T22:12:10.711271+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2022-03-20T22:12:10.711272+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2022-03-20T22:12:10.711272+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2022-03-20T22:12:10.711273+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2022-03-20T22:12:10.711273+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2022-03-20T22:12:10.711273+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2022-03-20T22:12:10.711274+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'commerce.wsgi'
2022-03-20T22:12:10.711450+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-20 22:12:10 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2022-03-20T22:12:10.735333+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-20 22:12:10 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 10 was terminated due to signal 15
2022-03-20T22:12:10.828903+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-20 22:12:10 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2022-03-20T22:12:10.832193+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-20 22:12:10 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2022-03-20T22:12:11.071588+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2022-03-20T22:12:11.233525+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-03-20T22:12:11.245918+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-03-20T22:12:16.055144+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn commerce.wsgi`
2022-03-20T22:12:17.101710+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-20 22:12:17 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2022-03-20T22:12:17.102057+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-20 22:12:17 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:29529 (4)
2022-03-20T22:12:17.102100+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-20 22:12:17 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2022-03-20T22:12:17.108078+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-20 22:12:17 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2022-03-20T22:12:17.110898+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-20 22:12:17 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2022-03-20T22:12:17.110899+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-03-20T22:12:17.110899+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2022-03-20T22:12:17.110900+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2022-03-20T22:12:17.110900+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2022-03-20T22:12:17.110900+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2022-03-20T22:12:17.110900+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2022-03-20T22:12:17.110901+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2022-03-20T22:12:17.110901+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2022-03-20T22:12:17.110901+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2022-03-20T22:12:17.110902+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2022-03-20T22:12:17.110902+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2022-03-20T22:12:17.110902+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2022-03-20T22:12:17.110902+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2022-03-20T22:12:17.110903+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2022-03-20T22:12:17.110903+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2022-03-20T22:12:17.110903+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2022-03-20T22:12:17.110905+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2022-03-20T22:12:17.110905+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2022-03-20T22:12:17.110905+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2022-03-20T22:12:17.110905+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2022-03-20T22:12:17.110906+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'commerce.wsgi'
2022-03-20T22:12:17.110966+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-20 22:12:17 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2022-03-20T22:12:17.118351+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-20 22:12:17 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2022-03-20T22:12:17.121512+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-20 22:12:17 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2022-03-20T22:12:17.121513+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-03-20T22:12:17.121513+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2022-03-20T22:12:17.121514+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2022-03-20T22:12:17.121514+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2022-03-20T22:12:17.121514+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2022-03-20T22:12:17.121515+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2022-03-20T22:12:17.121515+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2022-03-20T22:12:17.121515+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2022-03-20T22:12:17.121516+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2022-03-20T22:12:17.121516+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2022-03-20T22:12:17.121516+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2022-03-20T22:12:17.121516+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2022-03-20T22:12:17.121516+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2022-03-20T22:12:17.121517+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2022-03-20T22:12:17.121517+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2022-03-20T22:12:17.121517+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2022-03-20T22:12:17.121517+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2022-03-20T22:12:17.121517+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2022-03-20T22:12:17.121518+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2022-03-20T22:12:17.121518+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2022-03-20T22:12:17.121518+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'commerce.wsgi'
2022-03-20T22:12:17.121584+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-20 22:12:17 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2022-03-20T22:12:17.139816+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-20 22:12:17 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 10 was terminated due to signal 15
2022-03-20T22:12:17.238281+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-20 22:12:17 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2022-03-20T22:12:17.238305+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-20 22:12:17 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2022-03-20T22:12:17.380979+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2022-03-20T22:12:17.420553+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-03-20T22:12:14.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
```

TREE

```
Volume serial number is 78D0-83CD
C:.
└───TioArt-main
    └───commerce
        ├───auctions
        │   ├───migrations
        │   │   └───__pycache__
        │   ├───static
        │   │   └───auctions
        │   ├───templates
        │   │   └───auctions
        │   └───__pycache__
        └───commerce
            └───__pycache__
```

How can I resolve this issue as I've made several attempts?

Comment: Where is your `wsgi.py` file? `C:\TioArt-main\commerce\commerce\wsgi.py`, or somewhere else? And which directory contains your Git repository / is your project root? `C:\TioArt-main\commerce`, or something else?

Comment: Your app is not running in `/home/django_projects` on Heroku, so those lines are useless.

Comment: @Chris, yes, this is the path 'C:\TioArt-main\commerce\commerce\wsgi.py'. My git repo name is TioArt-main and the next folder after it which is the root folder is commerce 'C:\TioArt-main\commerce'

Comment: @Tim Roberts, I added that part because I saw it as an answer to a similar stackoverflow question (I posted the link above). Now, I see why the lines weren't useful. What do you suggest could be the issue?

Comment: Do you have a `__init__.py` file inside the "commerce/commerce" directory?

Comment: Yes, I do @TimRoberts

Comment: Are you sure you don't need `web: gunicorn commerce.commerce.wsgi`?  And note this is just a wild guess.

Comment: I'd check this @TimRoberts