# django mod_wsgi and apache: module not found error

Tags: python, django, wsgi

I am trying to move my django project to production using apache2 and mod_wsgi. I keep getting a wsgi_error "ModuleNotFoundError" in the apache logs.

I run on ubuntu 22.04.

After going through the various posts on the web I still am not getting anywhere, so I have now started from scratch by creating a new example django app. The same error occurs.

PS, When I use "runserver" the django app displays fine in the browser. Also a simple wsgi "hello_world" app runs fine in apache. So I think the basic setup is fine.

I have created a django test application "mytest" with django-admin startproject mytest

The project is created in /home/user/myprojects/mytest, the group of all directories is www-data

In mytest I have the usual django structure

```
home/user/myprojects/mytest
    manage.py
    mytest
      asgi.py
      __init__.py
      settings.py
      urls.py
      wsgi.py
```

The wsgi.py is:
(The django/python runs in a virtual environment I found that I needed to add code to the wsgi to actually activate the virtual environment)

```
"""
WSGI config for mytest project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

python_home='/home/user/.virtualenvs/myproject'
activate_this= python_home + '/bin/activate_this.py'
with open(activate_this)as f:
    code=compile(f.read(),activate_this,'exec')
    exec(code, dict(__file__=activate_this))

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mytest.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

The apache 000-default.conf is:

```
        WSGIDaemonProcess mytest
        WSGIProcessGroup mytest
        WSGIScriptAlias /mytest /home/user/myprojects/mytest/mytest/wsgi.py
        <Directory /home/user/myprojects/mytest/mytest>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
```

With this setup if I run "python manage.py runserver my_ip_addr" (my_ip_addr added to allowed hosts in the settings file) I can browse to my_ip_addr and the "install worked succesfully"  is displayed

Running through standard web (apache) shows:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mytest'

If I take out the django and get_wsgi_aplication part and add code to display Hello_World, like:

```
import os
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = b'Hello World!'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

Then indeed hello_world is displayed

However, I cannot find why the wsgi mytest application does not run

Answer (score 0):

It should rather be:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/myprojects/mytest/mytest/wsgi.py
```

instead of:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /mytest /home/user/myprojects/mytest/mytest/wsgi.py
```

Comment: Hello @NixonSparrow.  Thanks for you suggestion.  However, that would just point the main index page of the website server (currently locally accessed by ip number). The /mytest makes the URL in the web browser http://192.168.x.x/mytest in stead of http://192.168.x.x/  Based on the tests I did the reference should be fine (the hello_world for instance works), my feeling is it has to do with the django part of the wsgi and/or activating the virtual environment.

Comment: @henkwitte ok, you are right. But I have Django question then. Do you have `'mytest'` inside `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Good point, but yes 'mytest' is in 'INSTALLED_APPS'. Also note I can run the mytest app if I start it with 'python manager runserver ip_addres:port'.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it finally, due to this post:

[Django+Apache ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myproject'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42973991/djangoapache-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-myproject/42981216#42981216)

I had to add the project folder paths to the wsgi.py as follows:

```
sys.path.append('home/user/project/mytest')
sys.path.append('home/user/project/mytest/mytest')
```

The link to the django-served page is then:
http://ip_addr/mytest/mytest

The the comment by @NixonSparrow about the WSGIScriptAlias also made sense: changing that to  `WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/project/mytest/mytest/wsgi.py` then changed the browser link to http://ip_addr/mytest

The setup that worked is:

Apache configuration:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/project/mytest/mytest/wsgi.py
<Directory /home/user/project/mytest/mytest>
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

wsgi.py:

```
python_home='/home/user/.virtualenvs/project'
activate_this= python_home + '/bin/activate_this.py'
with open(activate_this)as f:
    code=compile(f.read(),activate_this,'exec')
    exec(code, dict(__file__=activate_this))

import os
import sys
sys.path.append('home/user/project/mytest')
sys.path.append('home/user/project/mytest/mytest')

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mytest.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

settings.py, installed_aps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'mytest',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('mytest/',views.index,name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.
    def index(request):
        return HttpResponse("<h1>MyTest Hello World ....</h1>")
```

Comment: Any idea what path to write when using docker. sys.path.append('???????????')

Comment: @Sardar Faisal - sorry I cannot help you, I do not use docker so I cannot test this